# What does the ^ mean for spec attribute in PhoneGap plugin?

Tags: phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

For example, I'm using `<plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="^2.0.0" source="npm">` in my config.xml to add the push plugin and then build my application with PhoneGap Build.

What does the `^` mean?

I [found](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/configuring/plugins/#plugin-version) that `~` means "greater or equal to" but can't find for the `^`

Thanks in advance for any clarification !

Comment: Answer here [https://stackoverflow.com/a/22345808/5283119](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22345808/5283119)

Comment: @MikeRodham thanks I was missing the english term for "caret" ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the simplest terms, the tilde matches the most recent minor version (the middle number). ~1.2.3 will match all 1.2.x versions but will miss 1.3.0.

The caret, on the other hand, is more relaxed. It will update you to the most recent major version (the first number). ^1.2.3 will match any 1.x.x release including 1.3.0, but will hold off on 2.0.0.

Source : [Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/whats-the-difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json/22345808#22345808)

Comment: If you're going to rip an answer at least post the [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22345808/5283119).

Comment: Oh I see, thanks !

Comment: @MikeRodham I updated